# ValueError while using CTGAN library generating the sample

Tags: deep-learning, simulation, generative-adversarial-network

I am using CTGAN library on colab notebook. I have passed on a tabular dataset, with one categorical feature. I have mentioned the categorical feature as given in dcumentation. The model training is also complete without error. I am getting ValueError, while generating a simulated data.
How to resolve this error

Adding a reproducible code below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from ctgan import CTGAN

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
iris.head()
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(iris['species'].unique())
iris['species'] = pd.DataFrame(le.transform(iris['species']))
data = iris.copy()

ctgan_model = CTGAN(epochs=2,batch_size=50,verbose = True)
ctgan_model.fit(data)

n_ctgan_generated_data = 2000
synthetic_data = ctgan.sample(n_ctgan_generated_data)
```

Complete error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-199b6dc04389> in <module>
      1 n_ctgan_generated_data = 2000
----> 2 synthetic_data = ctgan.sample(n_ctgan_generated_data)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ctgan/synthesizers/base.py in wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     48     def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
     49         if self.random_states is None:
---> 50             return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
     51 
     52         else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ctgan/synthesizers/ctgan.py in sample(self, n, condition_column, condition_value)
    475         data = data[:n]
    476 
--> 477         return self._transformer.inverse_transform(data)
    478 
    479     def set_device(self, device):

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ctgan/data_transformer.py in inverse_transform(self, data, sigmas)
    211             column_data = data[:, st:st + dim]
    212             if column_transform_info.column_type == 'continuous':
--> 213                 recovered_column_data = self._inverse_transform_continuous(
    214                     column_transform_info, column_data, sigmas, st)
    215             else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ctgan/data_transformer.py in _inverse_transform_continuous(self, column_transform_info, column_data, sigmas, st)
    185     def _inverse_transform_continuous(self, column_transform_info, column_data, sigmas, st):
    186         gm = column_transform_info.transform
--> 187         data = pd.DataFrame(column_data[:, :2], columns=list(gm.get_output_sdtypes()))
    188         data.iloc[:, 1] = np.argmax(column_data[:, 1:], axis=1)
    189         if sigmas is not None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    670                 )
    671             else:
--> 672                 mgr = ndarray_to_mgr(
    673                     data,
    674                     index,

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in ndarray_to_mgr(values, index, columns, dtype, copy, typ)
    322     )
    323 
--> 324     _check_values_indices_shape_match(values, index, columns)
    325 
    326     if typ == "array":

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in _check_values_indices_shape_match(values, index, columns)
    391         passed = values.shape
    392         implied = (len(index), len(columns)-1)
--> 393         raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")
    394 
    395 

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2000, 2), indices imply (2000, 3)
```

Is this issue from the library, where I have to change any source code?

Comment: Can you include the code that produced this error? Here's [how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @HiranHasanka
Sharing the code

```import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from ctgan import CTGAN
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
iris.head()
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(iris['species'].unique())
iris['species'] = pd.DataFrame(le.transform(iris['species']))
data = iris.copy()
ctgan_model = CTGAN(epochs=2,batch_size=50,verbose = True)
ctgan_model.fit(data)
n_ctgan_generated_data = 2000
synthetic_data = ctgan.sample(n_ctgan_generated_data)```

Comment: Please edit the answer and add the code there

Comment: Hope `ctgan.sample` part of the `synthetic_data = ctgan.sample(n_ctgan_generated_data)` line is a copying mistake. That would throw an error otherwise.

Comment: Also, unable to reproduce your error using the given code. It runs without any issues.

Comment: Yes, its an copy error
used cgtam_model.sample(n_ctgan_generated_data) in the code

Comment: @HiranHasanka
Can you pls share your env and python & library versions

Comment: I'm using Python 3.9.2 and ctgan 0.6.0 on a Debian 11

Comment: Can you pls check it on python 3.8.16?
I am unable to update python version on google colab

Comment: Checked on your version as well. Still not able to reproduce the error. If you run the code you have provided in the question, it should run without issues.

Comment: Thanks for checking, error was related to Nan values. Found [here](https://github.com/sdv-dev/CTGAN/issues/21) , that ctgan does not support Nans. The error log was misleading

Comment: As a practice, you should try to handle missing values in data before they are used in any other preprocessing step or modeling with any algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the input.
CTGAN using sdv library handles Nans inherently, I assumed the same to  be true with CTGAN library